# Using complex analysis to calculate the radius of convergence of real functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I did learn following Theorem:

> Let $f$ and $g$ be holomorphic functions in $\mathbb{C}$, if $f$ and
> $g$ don't have same zeros in $\mathbb{C}$ \ {$0$}. Further let $c \in
> > \mathbb{C}$ \ {$0$} be the smallest zero $\neq 0$ (i.e. for every
> other zero $w \neq 0$, $|c| \leq |w|$ of g). If now the function
> $\frac{f}{g}$: $B_{|c|}(0)$ \ {$0$} $\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ can be
> holomorphically extended to $0$, then the radius of convergence is |c|

Now there are some examples:
$\frac{z}{e^z-1}$, $\frac{z}{sin(z)}$

All examples where complex functions. Now my questions is, if I can use this Theorem on real functions too.

The reason I think this should work on real functions is:

If $\frac{f}{g}$ are real functions, that can be extended to complex holomorphic functions, then the radius of convergence in $\mathbb{C}$ would equal |c|.
The radius of convergence can't be >|c| because if $\frac{f}{g}$ gets extended to $\mathbb{C}$, there would be a problem with the singularity at $c$.
The radius of convergence can't be <|c| because $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: This seems perfectly reasonable. The radius of convergence (about zero) of any complex function is defined to be the distance to the nearest singular point in $\mathbb{C}$; most importantly, since $\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C}$, the theorem works for real functions too when we view them as the restriction of a complex function to the real line. For $\frac{f}{g}$, since $f$ is holomorphic, these are clearly the zeroes of $g$. A good concrete example is $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$. It's radius of convergence about zero is 1 as there are simple poles at $z = \pm i$.